# How to transfer my Picasa album definitions to Shotwell?

Tags: shotwell, picasa

I am still using Picasa on Ubuntu, but [Google ceased to support it long ago](https://googleblog.blogspot.nl/2012/04/spring-cleaning-in-spring.html), so I want to start using a different piece of software for managing the pictures on my hard disk, organizing them into albums (separately from their organization into directories) and uploading those to Google Photos.  [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) can apparently do all that.

However, I have quite a few album definitions in Picasa already. How can I export them or even import them into Shotwell?  I've found [software to extract information from the Picasa database](http://skisoo.com/blog/en/2013/how-to-read-picasa-3-9-database-and-extract-faces/), but it doesn't do this.